# Proving the summation formula using induction: $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = 1-\frac{1}{n+1}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

I am trying to prove the summation formula using induction:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = 1-\frac{1}{n+1}$$

So far I have...

**Base case:**

- *Let n=1 and test*

$\frac{1}{k(k+1)} = 1-\frac{1}{n+1}$

$\frac{1}{1(1+1)} = 1-\frac{1}{1+1}$

$\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$

- *True for n=1*

**Induction Hypothesis:**

- *Assume the statement is true for the n-th case*

$\sum_{k=1}^n  \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = 1-\frac{1}{n+1}$

**Inductive Step:**

- *Prove, using the Inductive Hypothesis as a premise, that*

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}  \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}  \frac{1}{k(k+1)} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} = 1-\frac1{n+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\frac{-2-n}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)-2-n+1)}{(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)-n-1}{(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{n^2+2n+1}{(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{(n+1)(n+1)}{(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{n+1}{n+2}$$

To prove
$$ 1-\frac{1}{n+2} = \frac{n+1}{n+2} $$
*Multiply both sides by $n+2$ to get an equivalent expression.*
$$ (1-\frac{1}{n+2}) * (n+2) = (\frac{n+1}{n+2}) * (n+2)  $$
$$ n+1=n+2−1 $$

Does this all make sense? How can this be improved upon?

Comment: Uhm, probably you wanted to say "assume that it is true for $n$", and move to the $n+1$ case.

Comment: This is a [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Comment: @Avitus Why and where should this be changed?@Lucian Yes it is indeed.

Comment: By the way, I don't think we would write something like $\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$ in the basic step. Try to write formally, like $LHS=...$ then $RHS=...=LHS$.

Comment: you are done: $1-\frac{1}{n+2}=\frac{(n+2)-1}{n+2}=\frac{n+1}{n+2}$, which is what you wanted to prove.

Comment: @Avitus Thank you. I just worry that I am unclear with my writing!

Comment: you are welcome; I believe your OP is quite clear now. On notation (and my comment above): if you want to prove some statement $P(n)$ by induction, then you "move" $n$. In fact, you start with checking $P(1)$, then you assume $P(n)$ to be true and you prove $P(n+1)$ using these information. Then, instead of "assume it is true for $k$", where $k$ is simply the summation index, I would write in the OP something like "assume the statement is true for the $n$-th case", or $similia$.

Comment: Ah I think I understand what you mean. I will try to correct that to make my notation a bit more professional or formal.

Comment: Please, do not forget to flag the answer you accept from the list below: this is the way to express your appreciation for the answer it helped you the most (and the user who wrote it) :-)

Comment: Great! The user @Ant has a nice introduction to the notation of proofs by induction. You can take it as inspiration for your amendments.

Comment: Assuming the statement is valid for Premise(n), P(n) being my summation correct?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309582/how-to-prove-sumn-i-1-frac1ii1-fracnn1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286024/what-is-the-formula-for-1-1-cdot-21-2-cdot-31-3-cdot-4-ldots-1-nn1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293244/compute-sum-k-1n-frac-1-kk-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you know about induction proof?

You assume that statement is valid for $P(n)$, and show that is then valid for $P(n+1)$.
(basically, you prove $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$.

Then, if the statement is valid for $P(0)$, is valid for $P(1)$, then is valid for $P(2)$ and so on.

This way you proved your statement for every $n \in \mathbb N$.

---

Back to your problem.

Assume $$\sum_{k=1}^n  \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = 1-\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Your goal is to show that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}  \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = 1-\frac{1}{n+2}$$

which should not be too difficult given the previous assumption.

Ask if you have any troubles!

**EDIT**

How do you manipulate that expression? The goal is to make the premises appear! So just do

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}  \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}  \frac{1}{k(k+1)} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} = $$

thanks to the inductive step

$$= 1-\frac1{n+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

You just have to prove that this equals $\displaystyle 1- \frac{1}{n+2}$ and you are done

**EDIT 2**

How do you prove that $$\frac{n+1}{n+2} = 1 - \frac{1}{n+2}$$?

You can multiply both sides by $n+2$ to get an *equivalent* expression.

$$n+1 = n+2 - 1$$ which is true, and so $\displaystyle \frac{n+1}{n+2} = 1 - \frac{1}{n+2}$ is also true

Comment: Well, I understand the statement is valid for Premise(n) and that I must show it will be valid for p(n+1) meaning we prove for every n the statement must be true. The trouble I am having is manipulating one side of the equation (in the inductive step I have created) to show n always with +1 next to it; As in I thought I could manipulate it so whenever you see any n in the equation it will be (n+1), then from there I can simplify to get my answer. I am unsure how to proceed. The concept behind it makes sense, I just think I have trouble getting the algebraic steps in between?

Comment: @mar10 edited. Is it better now?

Comment: Ah I think I see what you mean, let me edit my first post! I must sleep shorty, if I cannot figure this out, is there a chance you will be online tomorrow? It is very late where I am.

Comment: @mar10 I probably will.

Comment: Okay, I am slowly editing my post, I will let you know when I am finished with it!

Comment: Alright! I have edited it as much as possible for now, I end up getting n+1 over n+2 which is equal to 1-(1/(n+2)) although it does not look like it. How can I show this more correctly? Is this wrong? Thanks so much!!

Comment: @mar10 is it correct. To show that the two numbers are the same just multiply both of them by $n+2$ and simplify

Comment: What like [(n+1)/(n+2)] * (n+2) = n+1 ?

Comment: @mar10 see my last edit

Answer (score 2):

True for $\color{brown}{n=1}$:
$$\color{brown}{\sum_{k=1}^1\frac1{k(k+1)}}=\frac1{1\cdot2}=\color{brown}{1-\frac1{1+1}}.$$
If true for $\color{blue}{n-1}$, then true for $\color{green}n$:
$$\color{green}{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k(k+1)}}=\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{k(k+1)}}+\frac1{n(n+1)}=\color{blue}{1-\frac1n}+\frac1{n(n+1)}=\color{green}{1-\frac1{n+1}}.$$

Comment: Your method is much shorter than mine. Is this prefered and complete? I feel as though I need to put more steps in to be more specific and show I really understand it.

Comment: The principle of our computations is the same: add a term to the sum. This is what really matters, the rest is "routine" work.  I think you are putting a little too many intermediate steps. Also note that I used $n-1\to n$ rather than $n\to n+1$, as some terms are shorter. But the appropriate level of details depends on the situation. Isn't it nice with explanatory colors?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to prove it by induction when you can do it in a much more elegant way?
Use the fact that $\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}$ and the result follows directly, as all other terms except $1$ and $\frac{1}{n+1}$ cancels out.

Comment: To better my understanding with induction is why I am using induction in this case! The much more elegant way you suggest is great though.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} \frac1{k(k+1)} = \sum_{k=1}^m\frac1{k(k+1)}  +\frac1{(m+1)(m+2)}$$

$$ = 1-\frac1{m+1}+\frac1{(m+1)(m+2)}=1-\frac{m+2-1}{(m+2)(m+1)}=\cdots$$

Comment: What are you trying to say with this? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @mar10, By inductive hypothesis, $$\sum_{k=1}^m\frac1{k(k+1)}= 1-\frac1{m+1} $$

Answer (score 0):

Assume for $n-1$ then you will be very clear.
I am giving the final step only...
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}+\frac 1 {n(n+1)}=1-\frac 1 n+\frac 1 {n(n+1)}=1+\frac {-n-1+1}{n(n+1)}\\=1-\frac {1}{n+1}$$

Comment: This looks like a whole solution! How is this only the final step?