# Summation of $\frac{1}{k^2 - k}$ from $k=2$ to $\infty$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I couldn't get an idea how to get this summation?Can you help me please!!

Comment: Have you tried partial fractions? I don't know if it helps, but it may telescope.

Comment: Hint:  There is a well known trick which starts by writing $\frac{1}{(k)(k-1)}$ as $\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}$

Comment: why did anybody downvote man!!

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/286024/28900) for ways to determine the partial sums (let $k=n+1$). Also, I can practically guarantee this is a duplicate.

Comment: As for the downvote, I suspect it's because you've given no indication of your thoughts or attempts. Or perhaps because you seem to be yelling at us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that (for $k\geq 2$)
$$
\frac{1}{k^2-k}=\frac{1}{k(k-1)}=\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}
$$
so that
$$
S_n\equiv\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k^2-k}=\sum_{k=2}^n\left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right)=\frac{1}{2-1}-\frac{1}{n}=1-\frac{1}{n}\cdot
$$
What then can you say about $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n$?

Comment: Ok got it the answer is 1 !!Thnks!!

Comment: Isn't the telescope a wonderful invention.  Thank you [Hans Lippershey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Lippershey).