# Find the sum of first $n$ terms of the series: $\frac{1}{1\times2}+\frac{1}{2\times3}+\frac{1}{3\times4}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n\times(n+1)}$

Tags: summation, telescopic-series

> I have the series $$\frac{1}{1\times2}+\frac{1}{2\times3}+\frac{1}{3\times4}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n\times(n+1)}$$

I know the following formulas: $$1+2+3+\cdots +n=\frac {n (n+1)}{2}\tag1$$ $$1^2+2^2+3^2+\cdots +n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\tag2$$ $$1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots +n^3=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2\tag3$$ But none of $(1)(2)$ and $(3)$ worked.

Please help___.

Comment: PFD and telescoping.

Comment: I am pretty sure it has been asked before but I cannot find the duplicate.

Comment: @Rohan You probably mean [What is the formula for $1/(1\cdot 2)+1/(2\cdot 3)+1/(3\cdot 4)+\ldots +1/(n(n+1))$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/286024) (And also other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/286024).) Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%5Ctimes2%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5Ctimes3%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%5Ctimes4%7D%2B%5Ccdots%20%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%5Ctimes(n%2B1)%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to observe that $$\frac{1}{n\times (n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$$ $\therefore$ The given series can be written as $$1-\frac12+\frac12-\frac13+\frac13+\cdots -\frac{1}{n}+\frac1n-\frac{1}{n+1}$$ Each term will cancel out other term except $1$ and $\frac{1}{n+1}$ .

$\therefore$ $$=1-\frac1{n+1}$$ $$=\frac{n}{n+1}$$ Hope it helps!!!

Comment: :-P I know I can't type this fast on phone, so I just wait to up vote all these LoL.

Comment: @HarshKumar Thanks for the help. +1

Comment: @kovidvishesh. Thanks to you

Comment: @HarshKumar Nice Answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: We can write $$\frac {1}{n(n+1)} =\frac {1}{n} -\frac {1}{n+1} $$ Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, for $a_n = a_0+(n-1)d$,$\frac{1}{a_n a_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{d}(\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{a_{n+1}})$.

Similarly, higher order fractions $\frac{1}{a_n a_{n+1} a_{n+2}}
=\frac{1}{2d}(\frac{1}{a_n a_{n+1}} - \frac{1}{a_{n+1}a_{n+2}})$.

When seeing these kinds of sequence series, you can have a try to split items cancel each other.