# Find the sum of the following series: $ \frac{1}{1 \cdot 2}\,+\,\frac{1}{2 \cdot 3}\,+\,\frac{1}{3 \cdot 4} +\cdots\,+\frac{1}{100 \cdot 101}$

Tags: summation

> Find the sum of the following series
>   $$ \frac{1}{1 \cdot 2}\,+\,\frac{1}{2 \cdot 3}\,+\,\frac{1}{3 \cdot 4} +\cdots\,+\frac{1}{100 \cdot 101}$$

#### My Attempt:

$$\frac{1}{2 \cdot 3} =\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}.$$

So we can write question as:

$$\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{99}-\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{100}-\frac{1}{101}\\
=\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{101}\\
=\frac{100}{101}.$$

Am i right?

Comment: yes, this is correct

Comment: @Aka_aka_aka_ak thanks!

Comment: Minor note: your reasoning will be more clear and convincing if you write
$$\frac1{n(n+1)}=\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}$$ instead of just the case for $1/(2\cdot3)$.

Comment: See [What is the formula for $\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\ldots +\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/286024) and other questions [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/286024).

Answer (score 0):

_**Sum up of everybody else's comments:** _Yes, it is correct. The only thing I'd say is that as Theophile said, you need to make your prove more convincing, and back up *every single hole in*. A proof is never at an optimal proving state, but you can maximise this, by filling in every single statement you make with a law or rule, or in other cases, another statement. In the end, all the loose bits would be tied up, and your proof will be complete.